# Select all 'a' elements from a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I want to select a link with `some text` then I put:

```
$("a[text='some text']")
```

But didn't work, then I want to test selecting all links from a page.

```
$("a")
```

But this jquery select instruction only gave me the first or maybe the most important link of the page.

Why?

An example is here:
[image: Selecting links]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know that site is using jQuery?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn His code in developer tools seem to work fine.

Comment: @Vega He's right - `$("a").length` is "undefined". Something impossible if jQuery was used.

Comment: @h2ooooooo agreed, That seems to be the answer to OP question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Coding Horror does not make use of jQuery: there is no reference to the library in the source. If you tried `jQuery('a')` instead, you would receive an error stating that `jQuery` is not defined or it is not a function.

The reason `$('a')` works anyway, but only returns the first element, is because `$` is defined within Chrome's developer console, but as an alias of `document.querySelector`. This native method only returns the first matching element if any, unlike `document.querySelectorAll` which returns all matching elements.

There *is* a different command aliased to `document.querySelectorAll` and that is `$$`. Calling either one will yield all (256) elements matching the selector string:

```
> $$('a')
NodeList[256]

> document.querySelectorAll('a')
NodeList[256]
```

Both `$` and `$$` are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api).

Comment: Just to add – if you do want to quickly add jQuery to a site you're browsing, in order to play with it in the debugger, you can do so with the [jQuerify bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet/)

Answer (score 0):

the page doesnt actually have jQuery on it. Type $ or window.$ into the console. by typing $('a') you are using the chrome Command Line API. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api