# What is native $ function supposed to be?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was just making an userscript. I don't use jQuery on my own pages, but it saves lot of file size in userscripts - so I usually first check whether `$` is defined.

On my particular page it was defined, so I started using it. When I first ran the code, it failed. So I kept investigating how does it come that jQuery isn't defined in my userscript.

Soon, I found out that the `$` thingy is no jquery:

```
>>> $.toString()

"function () {
    [native code]
}"
```

But what the hell is it than? Browser fallback when jQuery is undefined? I don't think so.

This might be browser related thing.

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/$

Comment: Somewhat related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332869/select-all-a-elements-from-a-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a command line api function. Since `$` is a valid variable name, they've used that.

Actually it is a shortcut or alias for `document.querySelector()`, so it might be confused for jQuery but actually it isn't.(*Obviously, if jQuery isn't included*)